# Dynamic Array vlookup formula (Hlookup in a vlookup ??)

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm stuck with a complex array vlookup formula. 
Explanation:

- In one Sheet I have All location worksite
- In another sheet, I have all workers.

A simple goal, when a worker has a worksite write in his own line, import other columns via Vlookup. ( Easy )

But I'm trying to do something more: every worker have different type job
I want that the vlookup import a different column for every worker, base on the job type.

So, it's like the return columns have to be different for every worker ... (sound strange)

**it's like a vlookup in a vlookup or hlookup in a vlookup?**

Any idea how to make this work?
here, a link to the example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SY27Hw_Ck24RBJmh5n8hcyt3TrxTm1YPGDKU9DqA7xE/edit?usp=sharing

[image: image exemple]

Comment: so you want to create column G in column H using ArrayFormula ??

Comment: I find that breaking these types of "monster" functions/formulas down and then debugging the individual sections to make sure each part returns what is expected can isolate some of the problems (logic and otherwise).  For example, H5 has ref's two  hlookups(). The 1st attempts  uses the hardcoded text "worksite" -- this seems incorrect as a hardcoded value it would never change? Also this same call wants the (2) matching row, but the lookup is a single row (a1:al).   Could you provide a couple of sample expected function responses, too?

Comment: Ok, i just update the sheet, in columns H, a formula that import the data from only one columns ( like standard vlookup do)       In column I, the same formulas but more flexible? this one folow the column when you modify your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, DB_Localisation!A2:AQ, 
 MATCH(E2:E, DB_Localisation!1:1, 0), 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sC5Ka5hIZSBIt2ESjcGhxGq9FBVyujRwAmNspO1Cans/edit#gid=296991454)

Comment: Whaouuuu !! thanks player0, its work like a dream ! i maybe have to think about your solution because i don't understand how the match fonction do the job. BUT !!! It's work !! and it's great ! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using vlookup the second time it's better to use the combination of Index and Match functions. Like this you can get the offset index you need on the first lookup.

so being this my Sheet2:

```
+---+----+----+
|   | 1  | 2  |
|---|----|----|
| a | aa | bb |
```

in the first sheet I will have

```
+---+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| a | 2 | `=VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!A1:Z100,MATCH(C1,Sheet2!B1:Z1) + 1)   //bb`|
```

Comment: Sorry Alessandro buti don't understand what you mean. I try your formula but nothing happend (in the exemple sheet)

Comment: For me it works, try this: `=VLOOKUP(G7,Sheet2!A1:Z100,MATCH(E7,Sheet2!B1:Z1) + 1)`. Updated for your example sheet indexes.